# Take messages from a Discord server and take stock trades with it

Tags: python, stock, trading

I want a program (Maybe Python, but if you have a better suggestion I can take a look) that takes posts a user in discord makes and takes trades on a trading platform (WeBull) with it. What would I have to do to make that happen? Have a listener for the discord? Then have the program take the trade on WeBull?

Comment: Do you understand how to make commands on discordpy? What about interacting with WeBull? Just combine the two

Comment: No I don't I'll find out. Thanks.